# After upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 samba has big issues

Tags: server, upgrade, samba, 14.04

The server has been running very stable with 12.04 LTS for years but after upgrading to 14.04 LTS a encountered huge samba issues.
Directly after upgrade the mapping from Windows was toggling but there was a samba fix next day correcting this. It has run fine for weeks but after the last updates it doesn't work at all.
Yesterday I even tried to remove and reinstall samba without success.

Have read the other threads but it doesnt help me.
Everything looks fine in Webmin 1.680. Users and shares exists. I reentered the passwords but I cannot map any network drive from Windows anymore.

System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.

It is no DNS issue. I get the same error when using IP-address.
HTTP, SSH and ping works fine with host name.

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue too with the latest UBUNTU 14.04.

Each time the samba share was broken, I have to manually reimport the users by using smbpasswd  -a.

Why this issue was not solved till now during the long alpha/beta testing?

Answer (score 0):

I also have problems with 14.04 as a samba client.  If I try to keep open a file share from a windows xp host on an ubuntu 14.04 client, the share window becomes unresponsive after a period of inactivity, especially if I have switched to a different workspace.  I can no longer keep documents open across the share or browse directories across the share if I do anything else for a few minutes.  Nautilus errors out and fails, nemo and thunar will turn grey for 15-20 seconds and then start working again.  I never had this problem with ubuntu 10.04 or 12.04.  I still have 1 12.04 machine on my network that works normally.  All my 14.04 machines exhibit this problem.